# Boundedness of solutions to a certain system of "weakly-coupled" linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I propose a rather difficult question concerning the boundedness of solutions to a "weakly-coupled" pair of linear differential equations.

Let $f$ and $g$ be two continous real-valued functions defined on the non-negative reals such that

$$\int_0^{\infty}|f-g|$$

converges. We consider the differential equations

(E1): $y''+f(x)y=0$

(E2): $y''+g(x)y=0$

Let $S_{E1}$ and $S_{E2}$  denote the set of solutions defined over the non-negative reals. of $E1$ and $E2$ repsectively.

Suppose that every solution $\phi$ of (E1) is bounded and has a bounded derivative.

I want to demonstrate two things:

**1.** Every solution $\psi$ of (E2) is bounded and has a bounded derivative.

**2.** There exists an isomorphism $\Phi$ from $S_{E1}$ to $S_{E2}$ such that for every $\phi \in S_{E1}$, $\psi=\Phi(\phi)$ satisfies

$$\lim _{x \to \infty} \psi(x)-\phi(x)=\lim _{x \to \infty} \psi'(x)-\phi'(x)=0$$